# How to use one url for several actions based on profile information?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

### Context

I have different types of profiles in my application. (Three to be exact). I would like to use the same url for each type of profile and still have different actions. For example :

- Admins
- Compagnies
- Customers

Each type of profile has a dashboard showing different information. How can I use the `/` route for each of those profiles and still have different actions and views?

### Example

- `Admins` goes on `Admin.dashboard` and shows user stats, connection stats, etc.
- `Customers` goes on `Customers.dashboard` and shows last messages,
- `Compagnies` goes on `Compagnies.dashboard` and shows sales stats.

Each type of user is identified with a flag in session and is confirmed server side with database call.

### Solution

What I did so far is prefixing routes by profile type :

```
GET /admin/dashboard     Admin.dashboard
GET /customer/dashboard  Customer.dashboard
GET /compangy/dashboard  Compagny.dashboard
```

### Question

Is it possible to use the same url (ie. `/dashboard`) for those 3 profiles?

Comment: could you show us the kind of routing file you'd like? Because it's not that clear to me. And, if I understand well, if you'd like a route that is dynamic on the controller mapping, I don't think it'll work.

Comment: re-Reading the question and the @korefn answer, I think I got it... try another answer

Answer (score 4):

If the profile should be hidden from the URL point of view (not RESTful ^^). You can hide it, either in the flash scope or session one, regarding the length of the flows.

Now, for the routing part, it's yet another story. Since you can route (in the `route` file) using 'hidden' values, you won't be able to represent these routes in the configuration.

However, you could do you own Action interceptor that extract the profile and redirect to the right dashboard (this is probably the quick and dirtiest manner)...

At last, couldn't you just use the profile in the path ;-) ?

```
GET /dashboard           Dashboard.index
GET /admin/dashboard     Admin.dashboard
GET /customer/dashboard  Customer.dashboard
GET /company/dashboard   Company.dashboard
```

Controller... but doesn't scale for further calls if needed...

```
object Dashboard extends Controller {

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    request.session.get("profile").map {  p =>
      p match {
        case "admin" => Redirect( routes.Admin.dashboard() )
        case "customer" => Redirect( routes.Customer.dashboard() )
        case "company" => Redirect( routes.Company.dashboard() )
      }
    }.getOrElse { 
      Redirect( routes.Customer.dashboard() )
    } 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the dashboard isn't really a resource, it's a context sensitive thing, I wouldn't worry about being restful as the other posts suggest.  So, you have your profiles:

```
trait Profile
case object AdminProfile extends Profile
case object CustomerProfile extends Profile
case object CompanyProfile extends Profile
```

And you have a method that extracts a profile from the request header:

```
def extractProfile(rh: RequestHeader): Option[Profile] = rh.session.get("profile").map {
  case "admin" => AdminProfile
  case "customer" => CustomerProfile
  case "company" => CompanyProfile
}
```

You can just do this in your action:

```
def dashboard = Action { req => 
  extractProfile(req).map {
    case AdminProfile => // code here that loads stuff and renders it for admin
    case CustomerProfile => // code here for customer
    case CompanyProfile => // code here for company
  } getOrElse NotFound
}
```

Let's say though that you wanted the admins to be able to access the customer or company dashboard, and so you already have the 3 routes as described in your original post, so you can go to a specific one if you want.  You can easily add a fourth action that simply delegates /dashboard to the appropriate one.  Eg:

```
def dashboard = EssentialAction { req =>
  extractProfile(req).map {
    case AdminProfile => Admin.dashboard(req)
    case CustomerProfile => Customer.dashboard(req)
    case CompanyProfile => Company.dashboard(req)
  } getOrElse NotFound
}
```

Notice the use of `EssentialAction` here.  It's necessary if you want to compose multiple actions into one action.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these profiles are persisted in some form, a simple mechanism would be
to have a field identifying them and to use that field(from the table(sql)/document(noSQL)) to determine which features should be active or which templates to use.

Comment: That part is already managed. What I would like to know now is, how to manage the routing part.

Comment: `GET /dashboard/:id Generic.delegate(id)` with this when you have an identifier for a user you can the redirect to the required page is what I meant. all you need is an id.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one `Action` that handles the route `/dashboard` and have three different views, one for each kind of users. Once a request received, the `Action` will be able to know which kind of users is making the call and would respond with something like `Ok(views.html.customerDashboard)` for example.